# is file a child of given folder in PS?

Tags: powershell

How can I make sure if the file (result of `get-childitem -recurse`) is a child of given folder?

Usecase:
I'd like to copy a tree structure except those files/folders, that are children of given path.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where { $_.FullName -notlike "C:\path\to\given\folder\*" }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Post it as an answer :) should be sufficient except OP has multiple files that need testing.